# How does shortage of oxygen halt the NADH dehydrogenase complex?

Tags: respiration, energy, energy-metabolism

I understand that in the absence of oxygen the functioning of cytochrome c oxidase stops because it is its substrate. However I don’t understand how stopping cytochrome c oxidase also stops the previous complex (the NADH dehydrogenase complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a basic level this is quite straightforward if you look at an old-fashioned simplified diagram of the electron transport chain, such as the one below that I filched from the web.

[image: electron transport chain]

If oxygen is absent then there will be a build up of the reduced forms of each cytochrome. Starting from the bottom, in the absence of oxygen cytochrome *a* is not reoxidized; if there is no oxidized cytochrome *a* then reduced cytochrome *c* cannot be reoxidized, and if there is no oxidized cytochrome *c* then cytochrome *b* cannot be reoxidized. The latter is the substrate of the NADH dehydrogenase complex — NADH-Coenzyme Q reductase in the figure — so this reaction stops for want of oxidised cytochrome *b*.

(Years ago I demonstrated on a standard undergraduate laboratory class using rat liver (or perhaps beef liver) mitochondria, where you inhibited different stages and detected the reduced forms by their colours in the visible spectrum.)